# How to copyright my works in India?

Tags: copyright

I'm a poet and I write small poems. I know there is a lot to learn and update in the works I make, but how can I copyright my works? Is it one time for all the works or does every work need to be done individually?

I live in India.

Comment: Have you looked here? http://copyright.gov.in/frmFAQ.aspx

Comment: Your best option is to get in contact with an expert/professional in this field, i.e. a Lawyer

Answer (score 1):

From the moment your work is published, it is your copyright. Anyone who copies your work is breaking the law, regardless of where you are. It doesn't matter whether they are published all at once or individually, it still applies.

You are more at risk of someone copying your work before you publish it, and sending it to a publisher before you. Put your name, signature, address and the © symbol on your work to warn others not to copy. You should also keep rough drafts of your works as further proof of your work, in case it comes to court, where you can show how it evolved into its current form.

Comment: Does what you say apply specifically in India?  Can you say any more about the law that applies?

Answer (score 0):

Copyright is automatic. If you write something, you own the copyright on it. If you write something for hire, the person who hires you owns the copyright on it. Certain jurisdictions may provide a means to register your copyright,  but that is not required. You own the copyright the moment you create the work. Registration could potentially help if someone disputes your ownership of the copyright, but in practice this is not something you need to worry about. Copyright disputes really only occur as a result of complex publishing contracts, in which case it is a matter of contract law, or the creation of derivative works, in which case the question is whether copyright was violated, not who owns it.

In short. The copyright is yours, and unless you are a rich and famous poet, no one is interested in violating your copyright.

Comment: The OP clarified that he's in India.  Does that change your answer?

Comment: India is a signatory of the Berne Convention. Automatic copyright is one of it's provisions.